# How to read a file containing numbers in Octave using textscan

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, file-read

I am trying to import data from text file named `xMat.txt` which has the data in the following format.

*200 space separated elements in one line and some 767 lines*.

This is how `xMat.txt` looks.

```
386.0 386.0 388.0 394.0 402.0 413.0 ... .0 800.0 799.0 796
801.0 799.0 799.0 802.0 802.0 80 ... 399.0 397.0 394.0 391
.
.
.
```

[This is my file](https://bpaste.net/show/96cf21aa21b8) - for reference.

When I try to read the file using

```
file = fopen('xMat.txt','r')
c = textscan(file,'%f');
```

I get the output as:

```
> c =  {   [1,1] =
>       386
>       386
>       388
>       394
>       402
>       413
>       427
>       442
>       458
>       473
>       487
>       499
>       509
>       517
>       524 ... in column format
```

What I need is a matrix of size (767X200). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `textscan` in this case because your text file is purely numeric. Your text file contains 767 rows of 200 numbers per row where each number is delimited by a space.  You couldn't get it to be any better suited for use with  `dlmread` ([MATLAB doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), [Octave doc](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/dlmread.html)). `dlmread` can do this for you in one go:

```
c = dlmread('xMat.txt');
```

`c` will contain a `767 x 200` array for you that contains the data stored in the text file `xMat.txt`.  Hopefully you can dump `textscan` in this case because what you're really after is trying to read your data into Octave... and `dlmread` does the job for you quite nicely.